# Magento admin create customer chooser widget

Tags: php, magento

I'm writing a new module, and i need to implement user binding to custom model. I've created a field, named 'customer_id' in my model table with foreign key to customer id field. And now i need to add a customer chooser widget to my model edit form in backoffice. I imagine it needs to be a similar widget like cms pages chooser widget, that will return custoomner id to my edit form. Anyone knows, how can i do that? Can it be done by copying and modifying cms pages chooser widget logic? Any help will be appreciated